# Ambiguity when Parsing Preceding List

Tags: parsing, menhir

While writing parser code in Menhir, I keep coming across this design pattern that is becoming very frustrating.  I'm trying to build a parser that accepts either "a*ba" or "bb".  To do this, I'm using the following syntax (note that `A*` is the same as `list(A)`):

```
exp:
 | A*; B; A; {1}
 | B; B; {2}
```

However, this code fails to parse the string "ba".  The menhir compiler also indicates that there are shift-reduce conflicts in the parser, specifically as follows:

```
** In state 0, looking ahead at B, shifting is permitted
** because of the following sub-derivation:

. B B 

** In state 0, looking ahead at B, reducing production
** list(A) -> 
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

list(A) B A // lookahead token appears
```

So `| B A` requires a shift, while `| A* B A` requires a reduce when the first token is `B`.  I can resolve this ambiguity manually and get the expected behavior by changing the expression to read as follows (note that `A+` is the same as `nonempty_list(A)`):

```
exp2:
 | B; A; {1}
 | A+; B; A; {1}
 | B; B; {2}
```

In my mind, `exp` and `exp2` read the same, but are clearly treated differently.  Is there a way to write `exp` to do what I want without code duplication (which can cause other problems)?  Is this a design pattern I should be avoiding entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exp` and `exp2` parse the same language, but they're definitely not the same grammar. `exp` requires a two-symbol lookahead to correctly parse a sentence starting with `B`, for precisely the reason you've noted: the parser can't decide whether to insert an empty `A*` into the parse before it sees the symbol *after* the B, but it needs to do that insertion before it can handle the `B`. By contrast, `exp2` does not need an empty production to create an empty list of `A`s before `B A`, so no decision is necessary.

You don't need a list to produce this conflict. Replacing `A*` with `A?` would produce exactly the same conflict.

You've already found the usual solution to this shift-reduce conflict for LALR(1) parser generators: a little bit of redundancy. As you note, though, that solution is not ideal.

Another common solution (but maybe not for menhir) involves using a right-recursive definition of a terminated list:

```
prefix:
    | B;
    | A; prefix; 

exp:
    | prefix; A;  { 1 }
    | B; B;       { 2 }
```

As far as I know, menhir's standard library doesn't include a terminated list macro, but it would easy enough to write. It might look something like this:

```
%public terminated_list(X, Y):
| y = Y;
    { ( [], y ) }
| x = X; xsy = terminated_list(X, Y);
    { ( x :: (fst xsy), (snd xsy) ) }
```

There's probably a more idiomatic way to write that; I don't pretend to be an OCAML coder.

Comment: @checkmate: Thanks for the fixes. I did say I wasn't an OCAML coder, right?

Comment: haha, sure, no worries.  You gave a great answer, thanks for the help!